# Importation of Master data with standard validation

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I had **excel file**, **button (import)**, **openfiledialog** and **gridview** at VB.Net 2013.
My task is to make a button that will extract all data from **excel file** to **datagridview**

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\ProgrammerPC1\\Desktop\\DLAV FILES";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Import Master Data";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

try { 
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string name = "Sheet1";
        string constr = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1;";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr);
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oconn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$]", con);
                con.Open();

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
    }
}catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
```

My Error is 
***external table is not in the expected format***

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding the related commands, code snippets or configuration infos... Otherwise your issue might be classified as off-topic as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you're using same connection string provider (MS Jet OLEDB 4.0 Provider) for both XLS (for Excel 97-2003) and XLSX (for Excel 2007 & above) files, hence causing *external table is not in the expected format* error when trying to read XLSX/XLSM files.

You need to use 2 separate connection string and switch them based from file extension stored in `OpenFileDialog` with `Path.GetExtension()` method as in given example below:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName); // get file extension
    string name = "Sheet1"

    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection())
    {
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": // Excel 97-2003 files
               // Excel 97-2003 connection string
               string xlsconstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1;";
               con.ConnectionString = xlsconstr;
               break;

            case ".xlsx": // Excel 2007 files
            case ".xlsm":
               // Excel 2007+ connection string, see in https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/    
               string xlsxconstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1;";
               con.ConnectionString = xlsxconstr;
               break;
        }

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oconn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$]", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
}
```

Comment: It work!
BTW, rather than table data how about to show all worksheet existing in a workbook, How do I do that?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to "show all existing worksheet in a workbook"? Are you want to join multiple sheets in a single workbook file, or doing something else?

Comment: instead of having **dataGridView** to show all data, I want to get all worksheet of the excel file.

Ex.
**_excel1.xlsx_** have _sheet1_,_sheet2_,_sheet3_ 

If i click the button it will show all sheets in excel file.