# Error: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, excel

```
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection())
        {
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls":
                    string xlsconStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                    con.ConnectionString = xlsconStr;
                    break;

                case ".xlsx":
                case ".xlsm":
                    string xlsxconStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                    con.ConnectionString = xlsxconStr;
                    break;
            }
                using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oconn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "$]", con))
                {
                    // **There will be an error here**
                    // **The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.**
                    con.Open();

                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                    System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(data);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
                }
        }
```

What's wrong with the code? My purpose is to draw all database on **selectedItem** on **listBox** and whenever I click it will populate the **dataGridView**

BTW, the selected item was from the **MSExcel** *worksheetName*

Comment: Check what `extension` contains. If it's not containing any string included in `switch` statement, it doesn't set any connection string when `Open()` executes and throws exception like what you said.

Comment: I think you just need to pass the file path to the Path.GetExtension method.

Comment: I already check and change my `extension`. how do I executes and throws exception?

Comment: The `extension` variable in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287186/importation-of-master-data-with-standard-validation) intended to store extension from `openFileDialog1` control which will be used in `switch` to determine correct connection string. Don't modify it to contain the connection string itself, because any `case` inside `switch` statement will not trigger and actual connection string property is still null.

Comment: `string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);` I did this then do I need add another `case` inside `switch`??

Like you did last time to my **Question** can you show me or let me say feed me the code :(

Comment: Nope, you don't need any other `case` statement outside that 2 already provided. The connection string body should be assigned after `case` statement for corresponding file extension, it's not intended for conditional check with `case` statement itself.

Comment: still the `code` give me **ERROR Message**

Comment: update your code and the error message

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a very little fix:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Previously your GetExtension was trying to find an extension on your connection string, witch is impossible for the method, because is a connection string and not a path!

So your code fixed should look like this:

```
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection())
    {
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                string xlsconStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                con.ConnectionString = xlsconStr;
                break;

            case ".xlsx":
            case ".xlsm":
                string xlsxconStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                con.ConnectionString = xlsxconStr;
                break;
        }
            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand oconn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "$]", con))
            {
                con.Open();

                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(data);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            }
    }
```

Now your code will enter the switch case statement in order to initialize you connection string ;)